# Proving $(a + b) \cdot (e+ c) = ae+ac+be+bc$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

The multiplication of two terms say $(a + b) \cdot (e+ c)$ involves multiplying corresponding elements i.e. $ae+ac+be+bc$. How was this proved?

Comment: You  might be interested in reading the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621842/distributive-law-and-how-it-works) for some insight as to why the distributive laws are used and work the way they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just application of Distributive Law(s):
$$a\cdot(b+c) = a\cdot b+a\cdot c$$
$$(a+b)\cdot c = a\cdot c+b\cdot c$$
Specifically
\begin{align*}
(a + b) \cdot (e+ c) &= (a + b) \cdot e+ (a + b) \cdot c\\
&= a\cdot e+ b\cdot e+ a\cdot c + b \cdot c\\
\end{align*}