# Factoring the quadratic equation $3x^2-23x+14=0$

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I'm having trouble understanding how to factor this equation. Let's go step by step:

1. First I use the sum/product pattern:
   $$3x^2−2x−21x+14=0$$
2. Then I take the common factors:
   $$x(3x−2)−7(3x−2)=0$$
3. From this I should obtain:
   $$(x−7)(3x−2)=0$$

But I do not understand the logic that takes me from point 2) to point 3). What happened?

Comment: It's due to the fact that $(a+b)c=ac+bc$

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions regarding my answer.

Comment: Draw a picture: if you have rectangle $a$ units wide and $c$ units long, then the other rectangle that is $b$ units wide and $c$ units long shares a side with the other rectangle. Then just substitute $a = x, b = -7, c = 3x-2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a step justified by [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)

$$A(B+C) \iff AB+AC$$

in this case we have $A=3x-2$, that is

$$(3x−2)\cdot (x−7) =(3x−2)\cdot x+(3x−2)\cdot (-7)$$

See also the related

- [Distributive Law and how it works](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1621842/505767)

Comment: So if I apply the general distributive property to this particular example
x⋅(3x−2)−7⋅(3x−2)=0
is 
B⋅(A)-C⋅(A)=0
which by distributive property can be written as
(B-C)⋅A
and therefore
(x−7)⋅(3x−2)=0
which are the two roots, super clear thanks I just had to apply the general rule to the example!

Comment: @Pastille Exactly that’s the underlying rule we are using here! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** let $u=3x-2$, and take out a factor of $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using the [AC method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647073/how-to-factor-9x2-80x-9/647116#647116), three times the equation is:

$$9x^2 - 69x + 42 = 0 \implies (3x)^2 - 23(3x) + 42 = 0$$

so you just need to factor $u^2 - 23u + 42 = 0$ where $u  =3x$. This gives $(u - 21)(u - 2) = 0 \Rightarrow$ $(3x - 21)(3x - 2) = 0$, or just $(x - 7)(3x - 2) = 0$.