# Does the Distributive Law of Multiplication ever fail to be true?

Tags: arithmetic

Is there any situation in which the Distributive Law of Multiplication is false? For a specific concept, expression, whatever may it be. Is it safe to say that it will always be true, no matter the context?

Comment: It can be a property or axiom depending on your approach (see [here](https://themathpage.com/Arith/appendix4.htm)). How do you define multiplication?

Comment: Left distribution and Right distribution are two axioms of a ring. See the 3rd axiom of the definition of a Ring here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513223/example-of-ring-without-the-distributive-property So for a structure without distribution, have a ring without the two distribution axioms. Although now the multiplication is not really the multiplication you are familiar with. So the short answer is no.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621842/distributive-law-and-how-it-works

Comment: Yes, when dealing with floating point numbers on actual physical computers.